# Use specific VPN in Python process?

Tags: python, networking, vpn

How do force Python to use a specific VPN? The VPNs are configured and listed with `ifconfig` as `ppp0 .. pppn`, using PPTP. For a client I need to connect to an arbitrary VPN on a *per Python-process* basis. I couldn't find any examples on the internet for this use case.

The use case requires that a connection is made to a remote host using a specific IP address (which is on the other end of the VPN).

Comment: I guess, this task does not belong to your Python code and shall be resolved on system level. Python will try to connect to some IP, possibly specifying some network interface to use, and system has to react by using proper VPN.

Comment: The traffic needs to be routed on a per process basis; there are multiple processes running and each process needs to use an arbitrary VPN. Is this possible via routing?

Comment: Yes, I think, routing is the way to go (and it definitely belongs to system, not programming). Routing table shall make the decision which way to go, not your code. Trying to resolve the problem on wrong place makes things difficult and often impossible.